# unable to write on kafka topic created on kafka container

Tags: python, docker, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am writing integration tests and created kafka topic using docker command `docker exec kafka-broker kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --topic test-topic` in github workflow, Topic is created successfully. Using kafka topic in testcase to write data on
but it gives error `org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer`

Full erro message

> WARN ClientUtils: Couldn't resolve server kafka:9092 from bootstrap.servers as DNS resolution failed for kafka
> org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka
> producer  at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:440)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:291)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:274)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.producer.InternalKafkaProducerPool.createKafkaProducer(InternalKafkaProducerPool.scala:136)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.producer.InternalKafkaProducerPool.$anonfun$acquire$1(InternalKafkaProducerPool.scala:83)
> at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:86)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.producer.InternalKafkaProducerPool.acquire(InternalKafkaProducerPool.scala:82)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.producer.InternalKafkaProducerPool$.acquire(InternalKafkaProducerPool.scala:198)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriteTask.execute(KafkaWriteTask.scala:49)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.$anonfun$write$2(KafkaWriter.scala:72)
> at
> scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.$anonfun$write$1(KafkaWriter.scala:73)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaWriter$.$anonfun$write$1$adapted(KafkaWriter.scala:70)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2(RDD.scala:1011)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$foreachPartition$2$adapted(RDD.scala:1011)
> at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$runJob$5(SparkContext.scala:2278)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)  at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
> at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Caused by:
> org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No resolvable
> bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers     at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:89)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:48)
> at
> org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.(KafkaProducer.java:414)

I have a code as bellow

```
df = #df creation code
    df.write.format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9092")
        .option("kafka.security.protocol", "PLAINTEXT")
        .option("topic", test-topic)
        .save()
```

i want to run testcases in CICD. Can someone please help me how how to fix this?

Comment: Can you share the full error message please?

Comment: I have updated full error message now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a port number mismatch:
try changing `.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka:9092)` to `.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9093")` - from the topic creation command it looks like your bootstrap server is setup to run on port 9093 & not 9092.

Comment: I tried matching port but it gives error `WARN NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available.` and `ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test-topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.`

Comment: Have you checked to see if the broker process is running when you run the test? I see that you have a container, `kafka-broker` where you have created the topic. What is the ip address of this container? your bootstrap server ip address may not be localhost if your tests are running in a different container than `kafka-broker`

Comment: I am writing tescase and creating testcaontainer maunally. I have below commands 
`docker pull bitnami/kafka:latest
docker run -itd -p 9093:9093 --name kafka-broker--env-file $(ENV) -d $(IMAGE_NAME)
docker ps -a
sleep 15s #wait until service is up
docker exec kafka-test-container kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --topic test-topic
poetry run pytest \
  --cov=app \
  tests/integration/test_kafka.py

Comment: I can see in docker inspect  kafka-broker IPAddress is 172.17.0.2. I have this in .env file "KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9093,CONTROLLER://:9094",
                "KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9093",

Answer (score 0):

> DNS resolution failed for kafka ... No resolvable bootstrap urls given

Outside of the Docker network, you cannot resolve container names.

Option 1: you need to run tests outside of a container and use localhost:9093, the external listener

Option 2: Run your tests in a container, on a shared Docker network (using `--network` flag for Docker run, or using Docker Compose) and use `kafka:9092`, where the host address can be resolved, the internal listener

> in github workflow

Those always run as containers, so you're limited to option 2. `--network` flag isn't available there, however.

Start here https://testcontainers-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kafka/README.html

And also see https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/about-service-containers#communicating-with-service-containers

Comment: Thank you so much helping me  I tried.both ways but it gives error. 1st option -  I used localhost:9093 as a external listener  in code "bootstrap_server": "localhost:9093" but it does not connect. I have created topic successfull using docker exec cmd but it says can not find topic.
Option 2: gives error Failed to construct kafka producer. Unfortunetly I can not use TestContainer.

Comment: As mentioned, in a Github workflow, localhost will not work (your Spark executors are not running Kafka brokers). For the DNS resolution errors, I dont have suggests beyond asking Github Support for using networking features in a workflow. But you should not be using `docker run` and `docker exec` in a Github workflow, anyway... And why can you not use TestContainers? This is what it was meant for

Comment: I want to run testcases in all workflows in the CI pipeline will run inside a container. I have used used --network flag like this
 `.PHONY: integration-test-container
integration-test-container:
 docker run -itd --network network-name -p 9093:9093 --name container-name --env-file env.env -d bitnami/kafka:latest
 sleep 15s
 docker exec container-name kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --topic test
 poetry run pytest --cov=package \
  tests/integration/test_kafka.py`

Comment: 1) Poetry isn't running in a container. So, `kafka` DNS name isn't resolvable, as your error says. You don't need a network at all since there's only one container 2) I suggest using AdminClient in Python to create topics, as it'll also test your broker connection 3) use kafkacat to debug, as written in this blog https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: Thank you so much for the link. I already had created AdminClient but i was not able to connect :( that is why i moved to docker exec. But i see that error comming from my tests as code can not find kafka topic.

Comment: This code runs fine for me with your env file
`df = spark.read.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", 'localhost:9093').option("subscribe", "test").option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load()`

Comment: Is it because i am running my tests in container of the workflow which does not have access to the network created for the kafka container

Comment: It should, if you use [`services` flag](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/about-service-containers#communicating-with-service-containers) rather than manually do `docker run`. Look at the Postgres and Redis examples. Kafka is simply a different TCP service

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am getting an error I have posted another question. Could you please help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76344797/unexpected-value-depends-on-github-workflows-test-yml

Comment: I used services and refered your answer to someone else's  question to fix an error but no luck(replacing kafka:9092). Could you please help? here is the link to my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76353867/timed-out-waiting-for-a-node-assignment-call-listtopics-bitnami-kafka