# org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-kafka, github-actions

I have a docker-compose.yml file, running kafka server and creating kafka topic. running docker compose and tests from github workflow

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
networks:
  kafka-network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  kafka:
    container_name: kafka
    image: bitnami/kafka:latest
    networks:
      - kafka-network
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ENABLE_KRAFT: "true"
      KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES: broker,controller
      KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: 1@127.0.0.1:9094
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: "yes"
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9093,CONTROLLER://:9094
      KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_CFG_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CFG_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_CFG_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES: 5242880
      KAFKA_CFG_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE: 5242880
      BITNAMI_DEBUG: "true"
      KAFKA_CFG_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: "true"
    
  # create kafka raw topic
  init-kafka:
    image: bitnami/kafka:latest
    networks:
      - kafka-network
    depends_on:
      kafka:
        condition: service_started
    entrypoint:  [ '/bin/sh', '-c' ]
    command: |          
      "
      # blocks until kafka is reachable
      kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --list

      echo -e 'Creating kafka topics'
      kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --create --if-not-exists --topic test-topic --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1

      echo -e 'Successfully created the following topics:'
      kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --list
      "
```

test.yml

```
name: Testing

on: [push]

jobs:
  integration-tests:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, Linux, docker, ubuntu]
    container:
      image: app-image:latest
      volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    timeout-minutes: 15

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: "0"

      - name: Install missing system dependencies
        run: apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y make

      - name: Log in
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
       
      - name: Build the stack
        run: docker-compose up -d

      - name: Run Integration Test
        run: make integration-test
```

test_kafka.py

```
df.write.format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9092")
        .option("kafka.security.protocol", "PLAINTEXT")
        .option("topic", "test-topic")
        .save()
```

in make file i am running commage to run testcase -

```
pytest tests/integration/test_kafka.py
```

This setup works fine locally, but the github workflow fails and gives error `org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer`

I also chnaged `.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9093")`
git throws an error

```
WARN NetworkClient:[Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available.    
WARN NetworkClient: [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
    org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test-topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

I want to run tests in the CI pipeline, inside a container.Kafka server is running and kafka topic is being created on github workflow as well but connecting through python failes. Can someone please help me or I am missing something here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I got same exception, the root cause in my case was the value I set for delivery.timeout.ms.

I used get the exception for any-value lesser than 30sec.

Below config solved my issue.

configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.DELIVERY_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 30000);

Answer (score 0):

Your compose file is missing `ports` definition to forward localhost port 9093 to the broker

Comment: I added them later when I realised. But still the same error was there. 

Comment: Not sure. Like I said, your code runs fine for me, locally with those same environment variables. However, I actually wait for Kafka to start. I don't use pytest, though, just python since you have no assert statements

Comment: Okay! thank you for trying out. I have errors with both the ports kafka:9092 or localhost:9093

`b3a31a51aa89   bitnami/kafka:latest                                                          "/opt/bitnami/script…"    6 hours ago      Up 6 hours                  0.0.0.0:9092-9093->9092-9093/tcp, :::9092-9093->9092-9093/tcp   kafka`

Comment: 1) As suggested, use kcat to debug your listeners and ports 2) You don't need to expose port 9092 to your host

Comment: This works locally fine for me as well.  So did not need to use kcat. Removed port 9092 now

Comment: Now atleast this error is gone but it seems my test can not connect to the kafka server as it gives an error `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test-topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.`

Comment: How do you know your init container is successful? Or, that your Python code actually waits after the init container finishes?

Comment: I look at the container logs and i know the topic is created.I have blow steps added before kafka: .. to docker compse now. and in docker file i have a poetry run pytest command
test:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - init-kafka

Comment: Make sure it also is using `kafka-network`